# request, that save array of models in vapor 3

Tags: fluent, vapor

How can I update an array of models into `mysql` using `transactions`? and return `Ok` response after successful operation

Comment: Using raw SQL queries or Fluent ?

Comment: @nathan, using `Fluent MySQL` package in `Vapor 3` swift framework

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So, I solved my problem without transactions:

```swift
func update(_ req: Request, todos: [CreateTodoRequest]) throws -> Future<HTTPStatus> {
    let user = try req.requireAuthenticated(User.self)
    // 1
    return try todos.map { try Todo(todo: $0, userID: user.requireID()).create(on: req) }
        // 2
        .flatten(on: req)
        // 3
        .transform(to: .ok)
}
```

`.create(on: req)` returns an `EventLoopFuture<Todo>`.  So `todos.map` will return an array of `[EventLoopFuture<Todo>]`. The second step is to transform it to `EventLoopFuture<[Todo]>`. And the third step is to transform it to `HttpStatus.ok` response

Comment: This saved me. Thanks!